# How to save current user data using react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I create simple MERN app. I use passport in authentication.

I have **home**, **login**, **register** **secret** and **submit** page have. only loginned users can see *secret* , *home* and *submit* pages and only not loginned users can see *login* and *register* page. I send data using axios backend. User login,register was succesfully but after loginned users get user data many time after. I dont know how to fix this. My backend doesnt have error. It work well.

--------------  **Secret page** --------------

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import { user_ } from "../actions/register_action";

const Secret =  ()=>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const user = useSelector( state => state.user );
    
    useEffect( ()=>{
       dispatch( user_ );
    },[] );
    
    console.log(user);

    if(user === null) return <Redirect to = "/login" />
    else 
    return (
        <div className="jumbotron text-center">
            <div className="container">
                <i className="fas fa-key fa-6x"></i>
                <h1 className="display-3">You've Discovered My Secret!</h1>
                <p className="secret-text">Jack Bauer is my hero.</p>
                <hr />
        
                <a className="btn btn-light btn-lg" href="/logout" role="button">Log Out</a>
                <a className="btn btn-dark btn-lg" href="/submit" role="button">Submit a Secret</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
} 
export default Secret;
```

--------------  **actions** --------------

```
import { fail, user, USER_LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOGIN_REQUEST, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
     USER_REGISTER_FAIL, USER_REGISTER_REQUEST, USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS
     } from "../constants/all";
import axios from "axios";


const user_Register = (email, password) => async (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST });
    try {
        const {data} = await axios( {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "username": email,
                "password": password
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3001/register"
        });  
        
        dispatch({ type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data });

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL, error: error.message});
    }
}

const user_Login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) =>{
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
    try {
        const {data} = await axios( {
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: email,
                password: password
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:3001/login"
        });  
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data });
        
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL, error: error.message});
    }
}

const user_ = async (dispatch) => {
    try{
        const {data} = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: 'http://localhost:3001'
        });
        if(data.isAuth){
            dispatch({type:user, payload:data});
        }
        else{
            dispatch({type: fail});
        }
    }
    catch (error){

    }
}

export {user_Register, user_Login, user_};
```

Who have better idea? **Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try re-writing your `user_` action creator to be a function that returns a function:

```
const user_ = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:3001",
    });
    if (data.isAuth) {
      dispatch({ type: user, payload: data });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: fail });
    }
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

And then in your `Secret` component's `useEffect`, call the `user_` action creator to create the action:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(user_());
}, []);
```

I'm not positive this is the issue, but it does seem like something that should be done either way.

Comment: I write _user action another way but go one still. after loginned I go secret page but user data get initially null and page redirect login. after get user data. I need first time get current user.

Comment: why need return ? I see some youtube videos get user info like this.

Comment: I think that issue is because you're trying to select the data before you've fetched the data, so it's `null`. And you're redirecting away from the page. I think to solve this you're going to have to re-structure some of your logic so that when you select user you've already attempted to fetch it.

Comment: Where I find good tutorial about this? In mail.ru when some sent message to me in my page I see that time. it do redux. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't know off hand. If I come across something I'll post it in another comment and tag you. I'm sorry I can't be of more help.